# Change the language in the template and change the template style in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

i how with code can in template wordpress button change the language How can i do؟ that with change language,change template style
help me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link if you want to change the language
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-features/change-language

and for CSS styling go to Dashboard-> Appearance-> customize you get a separate tab for changing CSS if you want to customize valid theme from WordPress repository.